# Infinitescroll is not a function with Yii

Tags: php, yii, infinite-scroll

I get this type of error "$(...).infinitescroll is not a function" in error console of Firefox - which is very similar to this site: https://github.com/davialexandre/yiinfinite-scroll/issues/3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change these lines:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.noConflict(); 
    // Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
</script>
```

to these:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var $ = jQuery.noConflict(true);
     $.noConflict(); 
     // Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
</script>
```

It solves the problem. I still can't figure it out the reason.

Comment: You have something somewhere interfering with the $ alias. $.noConflict probably wasn't working because it was trying to call a noConflict function in the other library rather than jQuery.